# WPF InputBinding for hyperlink

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink, inputbinding

I am trying to bind Command to the `TreeViewNode`. For that I am having `TextBlock` and for action I am having `Hyperlink` inside it and `Hyperlink` is binded with Command:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TreeNodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=OneWay}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2 0 4 0">
         <Image Width="18" Height="18" Margin="0 0 4 0" Source="{Binding NodeImage}"/>

            <TextBlock>

                 <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=NodeActionCommand}" TextDecorations="None" Foreground="Black" Focusable="False">
                 <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>

                 <!--Following Input binding is not working-->
                 <Hyperlink.InputBindings>
                       <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding Path=NodeActionCommand}"/>
                 </Hyperlink.InputBindings>
                 </Hyperlink>

            </TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

This XAML working if I mouse click node, but On keyboard Key press `Enter` on Node of tree Command is not triggering. Please help.

Comment: It works fine when you allow your hyperlink to be focusable, and press TAB to focus it.  Perhaps you need to make the textblock itself have the KeyBinding?  This also would require it being focused/selected (and focusable!).

Comment: are you trying to have many hyperlinks in your tree?  if so, you probably will need to have the command send some CommandParameter or something so it knows which hyperlink is clicked or enter is called on.  Think about it, how will the user tell the app which item in the tree (hyperlink) is supposed to be acted upon.  Maybe your tree performs focus for you, i don't know, but it needs to be focusable

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen Yes in treeView I am having multiple links to show node of tree from where I am navigating windows. Problem with focusable hyperlink is that it throw exception when I switch from one node to other node by using keyboard array navigation hence I set focusable property to false. With `NodeActionCommand` tell class instance that which property suppose to navigate which already set while object creation. Now click event for command working fine but problem is as I say command not executed by using `Enter` key of keyboard. I can add more code or XAML if you want.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you keep track of the selected node (actionable item) somehow, so why don't you just do this:  register like this.YourWindow.PreviewKeyDown += Enter_KeyDown; then public void Enter_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                //enter key is down
                NodeActionCommandExecuted();
            }
        }                       and test for your actionable item null etc.